# Send form params hash as response content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to send back the forms params hash to the original referrer:

```
redirect_to request.referer, flash: { message: params }
```

Right now I am sending as a flash message.

Is there a way I can send it back as a response content or something instead of flash. 
I am not able to locate the correct syntax

Comment: I apologize, I only have  access to Safari browser right now and for some reason it is not lettting me update my message in a code tag.

Comment: You have to add an empty line before code to make it right (i guess you are familiar with 4 spaces).

Comment: yes I tried. I am having some weird browserissues. It wouldn't let me save the update. Thanks.

Comment: What you just did above will pass data using session, you can access it with flash[:message] in controller. What else do you need?

Comment: I want an alternate approach to flash to send back data as some kind of response content.

Comment: why you just don't use SESSION for that? It simple, easy to implement and obvious for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, Rails doesn't make it easy to issue a redirect and set the response body. To do that, you need to issue the redirect manually. E.g.

```
response.headers['Location'] = request.referer
render :json => params, :status => :moved_permanently
```

Note that not all requests contain a referer, so you should provide a fall-back location to redirect to. E.g.

```
response.headers['Location'] = request.referer || '/somewhere'
```